# How to re-render a map loop in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a sidebar with buttons links that targets div id and URL ends with #id_name. Now I want to render data that matches #id_name in a map loop using this code:

```
<div>
  {entries.map((item, index) => {
    if (asPath.endsWith(`#${item.section}`))
      return (
        <div id={item.section} key={index}>
          <h3>{item.title}</h3>
          <p>{item.summary}</p>
        </div>
      );
  })}
</div>
```

It works on refresh if #id_name matches item.section but if I click another link nothing happens even if item.section matches #id_name.

How can I re-render the map loop without refreshing or leaving the page when #id_name changes?

Comment: where do you change URL when click happens?

Comment: @abolfazlshamsollahi The button links href's #id_name and address bar changes.

Comment: If you want to detect changes in the URL hash, see [How to detect change in the URL hash in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69343932/how-to-detect-change-in-the-url-hash-in-next-js). You can then update a state variable to trigger a re-render.

Comment: @juliomalves I did figure it out, see my own answer. But thanks, that also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-render to work
asPath or entries should be in useState or redux state.
I think asPath is more correct one for this case... try using useEffect and useState

Comment: I did figure it out without using a state, see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure it out without using a state. Instead of using Next Link or `<a>` on button links, I used push from useRouter. Weird how that one works.

```
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleHref = (link) => {
    router.push(link);
  };

  <Botton onClick={() => handleHref(`#${String(item.section).replace(/ /g, "-")}`)}>{item.section}</Botton>
```